# Carregar automaticamente jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, fadein, show-hide, fadeout

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function (){
$('.check1').change(function () {//clicou em check1
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) 
    {
        $('.check3').fadeOut();//some check3
        $('.resultado1').fadeIn();
        return;
    }
   $('.resultado1').fadeOut();
   $('.check3').fadeIn();//desmarcou check1, check3 volta
   $('.check3').attr("checked", false);//check3 volta falso

});


});//]]>  

</script>

<input type="checkbox" class="check1" checked >

<div class="resultado1">Hello World</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="check2">

<input type="checkbox" class="check3">
```

I have a problem in this script, it only runs when I click the checkbox, but if I leave the checkbox checked automatically by html, nothing happens.

Someone help me in this matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute your handler once on DOM ready?

```
$('.check1').change(function () {//clicou em check1

    // implementation

}).change();
```